# Насколько / на сколько

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Правильно ли написано данное наречие?

`Насколько повысится температура?`

`На сколько градусов повысится температура?`

`Насколько вы вырастете?`

`На сколько см вы вырастете?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

***Насколько (в какой степени?)** повысится температура?  Скорее всего, температура повысится **значительно**.*

***На сколько градусов** повысится температура?*

***Насколько (в какой мере?)** вы вырастете?  Это будет зависеть и от вас тоже.*

***На сколько см** вы вырастете?*

**Словарь.**  **НАСКОЛЬКО**. I. местоим. нареч. В какой мере, степени. Н. помню, это произошло десять лет назад. Н. этот фильм лучше! Н. здесь теплее!

**Пример:** ***Очень вырос** в целом мире
Гриппа вирус — три-четыре! —
Ширится, растёт заболевание.*